# Deducing the Fermi sea is ground state for the kinetic energy operator $\sum_j(-\Delta_{x_j})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics

I am reading a paper and have no background in quantum mechanics. Any help/references would be appreciated.

The ground state for a system of $N$ non-interacting fermions on the unit torus $\mathbb T^d$ has the following simple form. In frequency space, $$\Big(\psi_N,\sum_j(-\Delta_{x_j})\psi_N\Big)=\sum_{p_i\in\mathbb Z^d,\,i=1,...,N}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^N p_j^2\Big)|\widehat\psi_N(p_1,...,p_N)|^2.$$
(This follows from Plancherel on $\mathbb T^d$.)

My question is about the following conclusion from this result. The paper I am reading says, *Therefore, it is easy to see that the lowest energy configuration is given by $\widehat\psi_N={\bigwedge}_{i\in F_n}\delta_i$, where $F_N\subset\mathbb Z^d$ is the subset of $N$ distinct lattice points closest to the origin, and $\delta_i$ is the Kronecker delta at $i\in\mathbb Z^d$. Clearly, the set $F_N$ is an approximate ball $B_{R_N}(0)\cap\mathbb Z^d$ of radius $R_N\sim N^{1/d}$, and it is referred to as the Fermi sea.*

My questions are:

1. How do I deduce from the equation that the lowest energy configuration is given by $\widehat\psi_N={\bigwedge}_{i\in F_n}\delta_i$, where $F_N\subset\mathbb Z^d$ is the subset of $N$ distinct lattice points closest to the origin?
2. Why is $F_N$ is an approximate ball $B_{R_N}(0)\cap\mathbb Z^d$ of radius $R_N\sim N^{1/d}$?

Comment: This must be one of those things that is well--known (to those who know it well). To begin with, what does $\wedge _i $ mean?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't know! What does it mean?

Comment: A reference to the article could help.

Comment: I don't think $F_N$ is even well defined. In dimension $2$, what are "the" closest $2$ lattice points to the origin? Of course you choose the origin as one of them, but you have four candidates for your second choice. You might have more luck on the physics stack exchange

Comment: From an energetic point of view, the four candidates have the same contribution though. But you're correct that $F_N$ is therefore not uniquely defined.